# PHP meaning of ./ for directories

Tags: file, filesystems

I'm learning PHP and I have been seen `./` used in the context of referring to directories. I've tested it and it refers to the same directory as I'm in. I would like to know what's going on; what's the meaning of `./` for directories?

Comment: It's an operating system thing, not PHP.  Works in windows, Linux, etc. `.` means the current directory.

Comment: Slow the downvotes.  If you don't know about filesystems and assume this is a PHP convention, then good luck finding an explanation at php.net.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Agreed. Not sure if that makes it a duplicate though, since this is a fairly basic question.

Comment: well its clearly off-topic 'Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. "

Comment: A philosophical point, @Dagon - is the question really about general computing hardware if the asker _thinks_ it's a language feature, or, more broadly, if it could be _mistaken_ for a language feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./` refers to the current directory. So, when `./foobar` is accessed, a file `foobar`, in the current directory, is being accessed. There is also `..`, which refers to the parent directory.

`.` and `..` are special directories used for filesystem navigation on most operating systems (UNIX, Linux, BSD, Mac OSX, Windows...). This pertains to filesystem convention, not PHP specifically.

Comment: Yes thanks, but for example if you use for example opendir('folder/'); will work equally

Comment: Yes, because it's in your current directory.`./foobar` and `foobar` are two (usually) interchangeable ways of referring to files in your current directory.

Comment: Ok man, thanks a lot. I though this was something from PHP i didn't know that was refer to the filesystem of the OS. Im just want to say the others people that nobody born with the knowledge and if i ask this here was because i didn't found it in any other place. Thanks.